# Hash Table, Multiples values in Key, Foreach Loop Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, hashtable, vmware

I have filled the keys with the necessary values,
Every key will have multiples values

```
$vms = @{}
$vms.template += $templateName
$vms.name += $vmName
$vms.EsxiHostName += $esxiHostName
$vms.datastore += $datastoreName
$vms.network += $networkName
$vms.FolderLocation += $folderName
$vms.vCPU += $vCPU
$vms.CoresPerCPU += $vmCores
$vms.Memory += $vmRam
$vms.IP += $vmIP
$vms.SubnetMask += $vmMask
$vms.gateway += $vmGateway
$vms.DNS1 += $vmDns1
$vms.DNS2 += $vmDns2
$vms.Description += $vmDescription
$vms.TrendMicroScanDay += $tmscanday
$vms.inventory_billing_owner += $inventoryBillingOwner
```

And now what I want to do is something like this because I want to use these variables in another commands.

```
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    #Assign Variables
    $VCTemplate = $vm.template
    $VMName = $vm.Name
    $VMHost = $vm.EsxiHostName
    $Datastore = $vm.datastore
    $NetworkName = $vm.network
    $FolderLocation = $vm.FolderLocation
    $vCPU = $vm.vCPU
    $CoresPerCPU = $vm.CoresPerCPU
    $Memory = $vm.Memory
    $VMIP = $vm.IP
    $SubnetMask = $vm.SubnetMask
    $GW = $vm.Gateway
    $DNS1 = $vm.DNS1
    $DNS2 = $vm.DNS2
    $Description = $VM.Description
    $TrendMicroScanDay = $VM.TrendMicroScanDay
    $inventory_billing_owner = $VM.inventory_billing_owner
}
```

It seems foreach loop doesn't work this way and I try to find information about it but was not possible
Someone know how can I work with a Foreach Loop and a Hash Table with multiples values per key?

Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks Mclayton for answer, I tried your solutions

First I want to send you what is inside of $vms

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> $vms
Name                           Value                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                        SubnetMask                     {255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.255}                                                                                             description                    {TEST, Test 2}                                                                                                               
Memory                         {4, 8}                                                                                                                       
name                           {Name1, Test 2}                                                                                                              
vCPU                           {4, 8}                                                                                                                       
ip                             {10.10.10.1, 20.20.20.1}                                                                                                     datastore                      {vsanDatastore, vsanDatastore}                                                                                               dns2                           {10.10.10.5, 20.20.20.5}                                                                                                     
gateway                        {10.10.10.3, 20.20.20.3}                                                                                                      
template                       {ESSQLTEMPLATE01, WIN 10 Template}                                                                                           
FolderLocation                 {Office Domain, SysAdmin LAB}                                                                                            
TrendMicroScanDay              {Day5, Day5}                                                                                                                 
CoresPerCPU                    {4, 8}                                                                                                                       
dns1                           {10.10.10.4, 20.20.20.4}                                                                                                     
EsxiHostName                   {es1esxi01p, es1esxi02p}                                                                                 
network                        {servers, data2}
```

Then with the first option running this for test

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $vms.template.Length; $i++ )
{
  $VCTemplate = $vms.template[$i];
  $VMName2     = $vms.Name[$i];
}
```

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> $VCTemplate
WIN 10 Template
```

I'm getting the second value, maybe I didn’t understand what you were saying

And with the second option, I was thinking what to use in the `foreach ($something in $something_else)`
but I ran this:

```
$vm3 = @()
$vm3 += new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
        Template = $vms.template
        Name     = $vms.name
        EsxiHostName = $vms.EsxiHostName
        datastore = $vms.datastore
        network = $vms.network
        FolderLocation = $vms.FolderLocation
        vCPU = $vms.vCPU
        CoresPerCPU = $vms.CoresPerCPU
        Memory = $vms.Memory
        IP = $vms.IP
        SubnetMask = $vms.SubnetMask
        gateway = $vms.gateway
        DNS1 = $vms.DNS1
        DNS2 = $vms.DNS2
        Description = $vms.Description
        TrendMicroScanDay = $vms.TrendMicroScanDay
    })

foreach ($vm in $vm3)
{
    write-host 'This is '$vm.template
}
```

And this was the result

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> foreach ($vm in $vm3)
{
    write-host 'This is '$vm.template
}

This is  ESSQLTEMPLATE01 WIN 10 Template
```

Comment: I don't see the duplicate key. I don't understand what the problem here is exactly. Do you get an error message?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from the foreach loop? What if the entries in your hashtable don't all have the same number of items?

Comment: I can tell off the bat you're doing it way wrong.  Looks like you want/need a collection of related data sets, but what you've done is create a collection of independent data sets.  Not going to work.  Need more info in your question to help from there.

Comment: Hi,
First I want to thank for your answer.

The keys will have multiples entries like $vm.templates = "value1","value2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `$vms` is a **single** hashtable object, and if you `foreach()` over a single object the loop will only run **once**. The fact that all of `$vms`'s properties (e.g. `$vms.template`) are arrays doesn't make any difference to this.

If you *really* need to use a single hastable with properties that are parallel arrays, what you'll need to do is something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $vms.template.Length; $i++ )
{
  $VCTemplate = $vms.template[$i];
  $VMName     = $vms.Name[$i];
  ... etc ...

  ... now do stuff with the $i'th vm ...
  write-host $vmName;

}
```

but a better alternative would be to create `$vms` as an **array** of objects with `@()` (note round brackets not squiggly ones) - e.g.

```
$vms = @()
foreach( $something in $something_else )
{
    $vms += new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
        Template = $something.template
        Name     = $something.name
        ... etc ...
    })
}
```

and then you **can** iterate over `$vms`:

```
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
    write-host $vm.Name
}
```

Comment: Hi Mclayton, I edited the post adding the result of my tests with your solutions
Thanks